# proto3.Any can not covert to JSON

Tags: grpc-java, proto

when i use proto3 to send gRPC message

my proto like this

```
service GraphService {
  rpc insertGraphData (InsertRequest) returns (google.protobuf.StringValue) {}
}

message InsertRequest {
  string tagName = 1;
  map<string, google.protobuf.Any> tagProperties = 2;
}
```

my client request entity like this

```java
InsertRequest.newBuilder()
                .setTagName("facebook")
                .putTagProperties("userName", Any.newBuilder().setValue(ByteString.copyFrom("zzz", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).build())
                .build()
```

my GraphRpcService like this

```java
@GrpcService
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GraphRpcService extends GraphServiceGrpc.GraphServiceImplBase {

    @Override
    public void insertGraphData(InsertRequest request, StreamObserver<StringValue> responseObserver) {
        StreamObserverDelegate.build(responseObserver).execute(()->{
       InsertRequest insertRequest = toJava(request, A.class);
//...
            return null;
        });
    }

    public static <T> T toJava(Message sourceMessage, Class<T> clazz) {
        if (sourceMessage != null) {
            try {
                return JSON.parseObject(JsonFormat.printer().includingDefaultValueFields().print(sourceMessage), clazz);
            } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
                logger.error("ProtoMessage to JSON error:", e);
                throw new BusinessException(CommonEnum.DATA_CONVERSION_EXCEPTION);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

   public static <T> T toJava2(Message sourceMessage, Class<T> clazz) {
        if (sourceMessage != null) {
            try {
                JsonFormat.TypeRegistry typeRegistry = JsonFormat.TypeRegistry.newBuilder().add(InsertRequest.getDescriptor()).build();
                JsonFormat.Printer printer = JsonFormat.printer().usingTypeRegistry(typeRegistry);
                JsonFormat.Parser parser = JsonFormat.parser().usingTypeRegistry(typeRegistry);
                String json = printer.print(sourceMessage);
                return null;
            } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

when i want parse the gRPC Message to JSON then throw the

```
InvalidProtocolBufferException: Cannot find type for url
```

i search smoe answer for the q,so i change method to use `toJava2()`  it also throw the same err, or ,the `toJava2()`  code has something  woring?

what can i do? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Any`, normally you want to `Any.pack()` a Message into it. See the usage in the [Java Generated Code](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#any) doc, and the examples in [the protobuf javadoc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Any). `Any.pack()` sets the `typeUrlPrefix` for you, which is used by `Any.unpack()` to determine the type of the message you're unpacking.

In your case, you use `Any.newBuilder().setValue()` directly, and don't set the type, so `Any.unpack()` doesn't know what type of message is being unpacked.

JSON printer converts the message to JSON recursively. When it sees an `Any`, it attempts to unpack it too. Because it doesn't know the type, it can't do it, so it throws the InvalidProtocolBufferException. See [JsonFormat.Printer.print](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat.Printer.html#print-com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder-) doc:

> public java.lang.String print(MessageOrBuilder message)
> throws InvalidProtocolBufferException
> Throws exceptions if there are unknown Any types in the message.